# R: easy way to skip the monotonous error messages with wrong version number with packages?

Tags: r, installation

This is irridating and regular error message

```
> install.packages('manipulate')
Installing package(s) into ‘/home/h/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.13’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Loading Tcl/Tk interface ... done
Warning message:
In getDependencies(pkgs, dependencies, available, lib) :
  package ‘manipulate’ is not available (for R version 2.13.1)
```

What kind of ways can you use to circumvent this? The RStudio [website](http://rstudio.org/docs/advanced/versions_of_r), for example, suggest a hxck

```
export RSTUDIO_WHICH_R=/usr/local/bin/R
```

but I feel there must be something easier or does one really need all R versions to pile up just for testing different packages?

Comment: Isn't manipulate an RStudio only package?  I don't think it's on CRAN unless I'm mistaken (which is quite possible).

Comment: ...this q is dumb but related interesting, for some reason -- there are massive quality differences over the GUI pkgs...still searching, not satisfied yet.

Comment: The question isn't dumb, considering that for whatever reason, upon install manipulate isn't availabe in windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manipulate is part of RStudio. There's no need to install it using `install.packages()`.

From within RStuidio, just type `library(manipulate)` to get started.

You can see some examples of how to use it at the [a RStudio website](http://rstudio.org/docs/advanced/manipulate). To my knowledge, it does not work outside of RStudio (eg running R in your terminal).

Comment: The gWidgetsManipulate package at https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=761 can provide a similar interface for non rstudio users.

Comment: @jverzani: moved the q [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9812547/r-gui-vizualiser-with-command-line-access-browser-based-letting-users-to-s).

Comment: On windows the following error comes up: 'there is no package called ‘manipulate’'

Comment: @ingrid, are you trying from R or from RStudio?

Answer (score 0):

Well.. I did have to install the manipulate package as shown below.

> library(manipulate)
>   Error in library(manipulate) : there is no package called ‘manipulate’
>   install.packages("manipulate")
>   Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Family/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>   trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/manipulate_1.0.1.zip'
>   Content type 'application/zip' length 35635 bytes (34 KB)
>   downloaded 34 KB

package ‘manipulate’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Family\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpYfnaHu\downloaded_packages