# R + Apache? Interactive R graphs and fast collaboration over internet

Tags: r, apache, unix, rgui

I need GUI vizualiser that shows R graphs with tickers and such things in RStudio style but over the internet (and notice with commandline access, not in RStudio). I hope an easy browser based solution, running Apache server.

**How can I fast show some of my projects or graphs in an interactive way to my collegue (not necessarily technically-savy)?**

Comment: You might add sage to the mix, though I'm not quite sure what you want. If you want to talk about gWidgetsWWW2 send me an email. It might work for what you want.

Comment: @jverzani I just found this: [RApache](https://github.com/jeffreyhorner/rapache). By this tool, users could share their plots to localhost and later elsewhere to achieve some sort of interactivity. Tried it?

Comment: Yes, gWidgetsWWW2.rapache is built using RApache as the backend.

Answer (score 0):

RApache is probably something you are looking for, [here](http://rapache.net/). You can find an example code [here](http://rapache.net/manual.html#rapache_Cookbook). I haven't tested it yet but it may be useful.

**Older stuff**

> I found the below material for some odd reason for this. I leave it here to get more refined.

- http://rstudio.org/docs/advanced/manipulate
- https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=761
- http://www.ggobi.org/rgtk2/#start
- https://github.com/jverzani/gWidgetsWWW2
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184517/a-better-gui-for-r (matlab/mathematica copy-catting)
- http://rpy.sourceforge.net/
- [Unix: Getting Mouse -coordinates over X like the Mathematica?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078575/unix-getting-mouse-coordinates-over-x-like-the-mathematica)